# Plotting the Hazard Function in R using survminer?

Tags: r, survival

We can use `survminer` to plot the survival function or cumulative hazard function, but I cannot see a way to use it to plot the hazard function.

For example,

```
library(survival)
library(tidyverse)
library(survminer)

data(lung)

# Run Kaplan-Meier on the data
mod.lung <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = lung)

# Kaplan-Meier Survival Curve
ggsurvplot(mod.lung)

# Cumulative Hazard
ggsurvplot(mod.lung, fun = function(y) -log(y))
```

Since the cumulative hazard function is `H(t) = -log(S(t))` then I just need to add in `fun = function(y) -log(y)` to get the cumulative hazard plot.

The hazard function is `h(t) = -d/dt log(S(t))`, and so I am unsure how to use this to get the hazard function in a survminer plot.

An alternative definition of the hazard function is `h(t) = f(t)/S(t)`, however, I'm unsure how to use this to get the plot.

I have found ways to get a hazard plot using `ggplot2`, for example

```
survival.table1 <- broom::tidy(mod.lung) %>% filter(n.event > 0)
survival.table1 <- survival.table1 %>% mutate(hazard = n.event / (n.risk * (lead(time) - time)))
ggplot() +
  geom_step(data = survival.table1, aes(x = time, y = hazard)) +
  labs(x = "Time", y = "Hazard")
```

However, I mainly wish to find a way with the `survminer` package, partly to have some consistency.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see anything in `survminer` that addresses this issue. Have you considered using a package that does have plotting functions for hazard estimates? Look at output from `??"hazard"` as a start.

Comment: There's currently no packages that plots the hazard function (I looked). Your code is seems to work though.

Answer (score 5):

A couple of years late, but here for others.

`survplot` can only be used to plot the hazard if the estimate was created by the `psm` function. The `psm` function of the `rms` library fits the accelerated failure time family of parametric survival models (defaulting to a Weibull distribution). Other available distributions are in the documentation for the survreg package:

> These include "weibull", "exponential", "gaussian", "logistic","lognormal" and "loglogistic". Otherwise, it is assumed to be a user defined list conforming to the format described in survreg.distributions

```
library(rms)
mod.lung <- psm(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = lung)
survplot(mod.lung, what="hazard")
```

For non parametric survival models, the muhaz library might be more useful. This example uses the default "epanechnikov" boundary kernel function. You may wish to explore different bandwidth options - see the [muhaz package documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/muhaz/muhaz.pdf).

```
library(muhaz)
mod.lung <- muhaz(lung$time, lung$status - 1) # status must be 1 for failure and 0 for censored
plot(mod.lung)
```

Alternatively, to apply B-splines instead of kernel density smoothing to the hazard, have a look at the `bshazard` library

```
library(bshazard)
mod.lung <- bshazard(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = lung)
plot(mod.lung)
```